# Use MySQL and SQLite simultaneously

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc

I created a simple SQLite connection using Java.
Now I want to activate MySQL simultaneously as an option to store the data online.

Is there an easier way than rewriting every method to use the MySQL connection? E.g. create a connection object with both JDBC Drivers at once, so I have only one connection variable?

Comment: You should check this http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

> E.g. create a connection object with both JDBC Drivers at once, so I have only one connection variable?

Short answer: No. You cannot use a single JDBC `Connection` object to update two completely different database systems. You couldn't even use a single JDBC `Connection` object to update the same type of database (e.g., SQLite or MySQL) in two different places unless you had some sort of replication enabled between the databases themselves.

If you re-vamped your code to work with your own custom Objects (Classes) then you could conceivably code those classes to persist the data in SQLite and/or MySQL, but that would still require separate connections to each database.